# How can I Count Instances of Search Terms in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I'm working with internal site search terms from Google Analytics in Google Data Studio. I need to count how many times users searched specific terms on the website. The problem is, the data is case sensitive and users often misspell words when they search, so that won't get tallied in a normal count function. For example, "careers", "Careers", "cAREERS", and "carers" are all different searches. What formula can I use to easily count how many times users searched different terms?

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Updating the question with 10 or so rows of sample data (removing or replacing any sensitive information) showing the current data set (just the fields relevant to this question) and the output (expected result) would allow users to reproduce the issue and provide a suggestion specific to the table of data provided, using the specified field names; also note that [Formatted Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) are preferred to images of Tables

Answer (score 0):

First add a field with the formula `LOWER`. Then add a field with `case when` to correct each possible spelling errors.

Another route would be to create a "sounds like" field. Here BigQuery give a nice function `SOUNDEX`. Data Studio does not offer somthing like that, but you can build a function with reg_exs so that: first character of word and then only the vocals of the word, but remove duplicated vocals first.